# NodeJS HTML to PDF then add password

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream

Is there a way to add password on PDF using nodejs? here is the catch:

1. Convert HTML to PDF (buffer/stream result)
2. Then tru that buffer/stream result, add/protect pdf with password

I want buffer because i don't want to create a file on project directory and then delete if after.

That buffer result with already protected pdf password will be uploaded to S3 bucket

anyone can help me ?